# Ninject in a three tier application

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ninject, n-tier-architecture

I am building a standard three tier app.

1 Console app for front end

2 Business logic layer

3 Data layer

The main purpose is to display some customer data from a database table.

I'm trying to follow the guide lines in the book "Dependency Injection in .NET"  by having no reference from the console to the data layer, and none from the business layer to the data layer. Allowing for easy swapping of the front end and the data layers if needed.

Let's say I have a service at the business layer called CustomerService and it has a `GetCustomers()` method

the constructor of `CustomerService` takes an `ICustomerRepository` like so

```
 public class CustomerService 
 {
     ICustomerRepository repository; 

     public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository repository) 
     {
        this.repository = repository;
     }

     public ICollection<Customer> GetCustomers() 
     {
         return repository.GetCustomers();
     }
}
```

At the data layer I have

```
public class CustomerRepository : BLL.ICustomerRepository 
{
    public ICollection<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
         // get the customers from the db 
         return customers;
    }
}
```

In the console app I want to call the create a CustomerService object using Ninject to fulfil the ICustomerRepository dependency.

```
 class DIModule : NinjectModule
 {
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<>(ICustomerRepository).To<??????????????>()
    }
 }
```

How can I bind to the data layers CustomerRepository class? I would have to add a reference from the console app to the data layer for this to work? 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Bind<ICustomerRepository>().To<CustomerRepository>();
```

Comment: Won't that require my console application having a reference to my data layer? I want to avoid that.

Comment: @tom: IoC is just layer of abstraction. When register dependencies you need a reference for both contract (interface) and service (implementation) so need to reference assembly containing both. Then you never use concrete class type anywhere down road.

Comment: Came across similar sentiments in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994507/dependency-injection-does-it-violate-separation-of-concerns  Still getting used to DI. Thanks.